# Import 64bit floating point value from binary file into python

Tags: python, matlab, binary

Background:
Good day, I need to extract information from a binary file produced by an equipment. The equipment comes with a matlab function to import binary file. From what i understand from the manual, the binary file contains a 64-bit floating point value between 0 and 1.

```
function phase = importData(folder, qUnit);

fileName = sprintf('%s\\%s.PH', folder, qUnit);

file = fopen(fileName, 'rb');

fseek(file, 0, 'bof');
phase = fread(file, inf, 'float64');
```

Question: The matlab function works fine, but I wish to import the data into python. May I know how can this be done on Python? I did some research myself and tried something like this at the bottom. But when I do print(fileContent) to check the imported data, python simply stops responding in windows.

```
with open('sample.PH', mode='rb') as binary_file: 
    fileContent = binary_file.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read binary files like that into a useful form. You should use [`numpy.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). This will give you a numerical vector with the data, similar to what you would get in MATLAB.  You don't even need to open it (although you can if you want).  Just give it a filename and it will automatically open, read, then close the file for you.

```
import numpy as np

file_content = np.fromfile('sample.PH', np.float64)
```

Edit: here is how you can do multiple repeated values:

```
import numpy as np

file_content = np.fromfile('sample.PH', [('data', np.float32), 
                                         ('time', np.float64)])
```

(I put the last line on two lines for clarity, it could be one line if you prefer, or 10 for that matter, python doesn't care)

This will give you the equivalent of a MATLAB `struct` where one field is the data and the other field is the time. You can then access the data using `file_content['data']` and the time using `file_content['time']`.  There is more information at the link I provided above.

Comment: Thank you very much TheBlackCat. You've been a great help, your method works!

I just realized I had another issue, one of the binary file I'm working with contains a 32-bit floating point value Data, immediately followed by a 64-bit value representing the time at which the Data was recorded.

This is how it looks like in the provided Matlab function.
`code` fseek(file, 0, 'bof');
data = fread(file, inf, 'float32', 8);
fseek(file, 4, 'bof');
data_tm = fread(file, inf, 'float64', 4);
`code`
Can this be implemented using numpy? Edit:sorry for messy post, insert new line doesnt work.

Comment: @RaymondWong I just updated my answer to answer this question. Please look at my answer again.  Also, if this answers your question please mark it as accepted.